# The expectation value of the energy of the general wave function in the infinite square well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hilbert-space, wavefunction, superposition

We know in the infinite square well that the general solution is a linear combination of the stationary states ( states with definite energy eigenvalues). Also the measurement of the energy for that wave function at any time would yield one of those eigenvalues, with some certain probability. My question is: What is the physical interpretation of the "expectation value of the energy" for the general wave function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the average of the energies you would measure if you performed many measurements on identical wave functions. Practically speaking, it may be useful if you are dealing with a large ensemble of particles all in the same state. Often, the expectation value of an observable will never actually correspond to the results of a single measurement, unless the expectation value happens to also be an eigenvalue. It is also impossible to figure out the expectation value based solely on a single measurement. You need to know the wave function.

Answer (score 3):

As it is expected from its name, "expectation value" is the value we expect the particle to have, even though in general it is not equal to any of its eigenvalues! A similar situation arise when we consider the center of mass of a ring; it is inside the ring where there is no actual mass, but that is not a problem because the center of mass is just a representative of the position of the object.
The same is true for the expectation value of the energy or any other expectation values; it is a representative for the amount of energy the particle has.
You can ask the same question about the expectation value of the position of the particle, is there any similarity to the center of mass?